# How to query datediff in Hive?

Tags: hive

I have 3 columns named:

- Call received time
- Call dispatch time
- call cleared time

I want to generate a query which will give me the output:

> *call dispatch time* - *call received time*
>   *call cleared time* - *call dispatch time*

How can I do that in Hive Query Language?

Answer (score 0):

Use `unix_timestamp()` to convert timestamp to seconds, then substract, then divide by 60 if you want result in minutes:

```
select (unix_timestamp(call_dispatch_time) - unix_timestamp(call_received_time))/60 as diff_received,
       (unix_timestamp(call_cleared_time) - unix_timestamp(call_dispatch_time))/60 as diff_cleared
```

Remove `/60` if you want result in seconds